# Strange blank space showing up in page. Possibly CSS?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, css

I've got a real problem here. I have a page at: [page removed]
and if you go to it, it loads fine, but then the middle contents "shift" over to the right, and only in the top paragraph and headline. In particular, I'm talking about the headline "Pipes" and the paragraph that follows. They should be left aligned like the rest of the centre content. The problem isn't the position of the divs, it's the header and paragraph moving after the page loads.
I've removed almost all the CSS to try and find out what is doing this but I'm not certain it is CSS-related and I can't think of anything else to try.
I've tried to use every tool I can think of and there doesn't seem to be anything actually there in the code that would "shift" the copy over so I'm trying to see if someone else has an idea that I could try.
The page is done in classic ASP, with HTML5 and CSS3, and a little jQuery just fyi.
If you need to see code, let me know. I am baffled at what is doing this, I've never seen anything behave like this.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't pinpoint the exact reason, the issue is with your `#logo` element.

If you remove it, or give it absolute positioning in order to take it out of the flow, the `<p>` in question is corrected.

Comment: OMG - Thank you, that did it. I have to reposition a few things but that was the problem!

Comment: @stephmoreland - You're welcome. Part of it has to do with the logo, the top nav, and maybe some other elements having `float:left`. Like you said, a little different positioning approach, and you'll be set. :o)

Comment: I have spent HOURS trying everything I could think of, once again thank you so much, you've saved my weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Set **width** in body to auto
Set **left**, **right** in interior_wrap to auto

Comment: OK, I set the body width to auto, and the left, right of interior_wrap to auto. The problem is with the paragraph that starts "Pipes" and the paragraph below, they should be aligned to the left like the rest of the copy in the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
position: absolute;
margin-left: -460px;
left: 50%;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great tip to remember, but I edited my question because the problem isn't the position of the divs.

Comment: BTW, you need to change the z-index of your flyouts

Comment: What should I change them to?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the section#logo. This is floated, and then repositioned, but not taken out of page flow, so text is still wrapping around it. Set "position: absolute" on #logo and it'll be fine.